# At least five out of twenty lottery tickets win probability

Tags: probability

There are $1000$ lottery tickets, $50$ of them win. We buy $20$ of these tickets. What is the probability that at least $5$ of them will win?

(I'm trying to solve this problem in a similar way as solving the at least one problem, but I'm not getting any appropriate results.)

thanks

Comment: Have a look at [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: @drhab, you can approximate it to Biinomial with N = 1000 being too large

Answer (score 0):

$p = \frac{50}{1000} = 0.05$

As @drhab as mentioned,it strictly follows hypergeometric but can be approximated using binomial as $N =1000$ is very large compared to $20$ being sampled

$$P(X=k) = {20\choose  k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$$

Required Prob $= 1-\sum_{i=0}^{4} P(X=i)$